# Git repository name does not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm doing a ruby on rails project using Heroku to run my app and I came across a very annoying problem. I had a lot of bugs in my app so I decided to erase my app and deploy again on to a new app. The thing is, whenever I try

```
>> heroku create  \\ works as intended
>> git push heroku master \\ tries to push using the erased app name, fails
>> remote: !       No such app as old-app-75226.
```

how do I tell the system, in this case C9, that I want it to push to the new app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to detach your repository from heroku first and create again

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku create
git push heroku master
```